# How to convert a non-nullable type to a nullable type?

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

Is it possible to convert a non-nullable value type known only at runtime to nullable? In other words:

```
public Type GetNullableType(Type t)
{
    if (t.IsValueType)
    {
        return typeof(Nullable<t>);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Obviously the `return` line gives an error. Is there a way to do this? The `Type.MakeGenericType` method seems promising, but I have no idea how to get a unspecified generic `Type` object representing `Nullable<T>`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you want `typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(t)`

Note: `Nullable<>` **without** any supplied arguments is the unbound generic type; for more complex examples, you would add commas to suit - i.e. `KeyValuePair<,>`, `Tuple<,,,>` etc.

Comment: Thanks! I searched the entire typeof() documentation and couldn't find anything about generics.

Comment: @jjoelson - note you should also check the underlying type, as you are not allowed to create `Nullable<Nullable<int>>` etc - consider: what if `t == typeof(float?)` (which has `.ValueType === true` )

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track. Try this:

```
if (t.IsValueType)
{
    return typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(t);
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Type GetNullableType(Type type) {
    // Use Nullable.GetUnderlyingType() to remove the Nullable<T> wrapper
    // if type is already nullable.
    type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    if (type.IsValueType)
        return typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    else
        return type;
}
```

Comment: any chance you can format that correctly? indent the text 4 characters to get code recognition, etc

Comment: That doesn't actually do what we want here, since passing in `typeof(int)` will throw an exception (`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)` will return `null`)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to return the UnderlyingSystemType of the first of the GenericTypeArguments.  So in this example, a Nullable Datetime? is returning as the property type and I need to convert it to a Datetime type so it can be added to a DataTable.  This should work with int? and double? etc.

```c#
if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) != null) {
  tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First().UnderlyingSystemType);
} else {
  tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
}
```